# how do i display my page depending on the users screen size

Tags: android, html, css

is there any method maybe using php (excluding js/jquery as i don't know how to use it) to get the users screensize and use it to make the css work with that

for example if i use percentages instead of pixels to set up my heights and widths it still doesn't respond to the screen size of my phone and the user has to zoom in to see the information clearly, it doesn't make it bigger, and by that i don't only mean text, images and html elements such as divs/spans/w.e....

also i don't want to use bootstrap, i want to understand how it works, using bootstrap is like driving an automatic car without knowing how to drive a manual...

Comment: Media Queries.  read about them.

Comment: A typical responsiveness solution is based on [@media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). That's a fancy name for conditional wrappers around your CSS code. The CSS wrapped in the query only applies if the condition is true.

Comment: why do i always get a negative rating on the question when i ask it, i have tried searching for ways of doing this and i can't find it, if i could i wouldn't ask, people would rather -1 a question than give directions, pure ignorance, anyway thank you/multumesc andrei, o sa citesc despre media queries

Answer (score 1):

One essential thing in web design for smaller devices is to include this in the header of all pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"; initial-scale="1.0" />
```

It deactivates the automatic "shrinking"/downzooming of the page content to the current viewport (= screen) size, which is important for smartphones and tablets. A pixel remains a pixel, so if your smartphone screen is only 320px wide, that's what's the width limit in absolute pixels.

If this isn't included, the built-in automatic  just interprets the width of a non-responsive page as 100% and compresses it to the width of the device, which will result in tiny fonts and images, which you can see in every non-repsonsive website.

After that, you'll have to become friends with media queries...

Answer (score 0):

There are some frameworks tha will help you get this kind of behavior. One of the easiest ones to use is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It is very easy to setup and understand.  It uses a grid to determine the size of the elements in your page relative to the width of the device. Also, there are many prebuilt items that might help you getting started.

Another useful framework is [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), the concept is very similar to twitter bootstrap. Altough it is more flexible it requires a bit more time to lear how to use it.

If you are going to do the adaptative functionality by yourself, or if you are interested in learning how this is actually done you should investigate media querys.